# How can I create a struct parameter for a llvm IR call instruction?

Tags: c++, struct, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to insert a function call instruction into an IR file. But there are some problems when I tried to create a struct parameter.

function:

```
 "__myfun(int addr,struct buginfor struct_var)"
```

the struct is:

```
 typedef struct buginfor{
    int line;
    char *str1;
    char *str2;
 };
```

my code:

```
Value* args[] = { addr };

// struct parameter create
Value *struct_line = ConstantInt::get(IntegerType::get(M->getContext(), 64), 4);
Value *struct_filename= llvm::PointerType::get(IntegerType::get(M->getContext(), 8),20);//20 bytes
Value *struct_dir= llvm::PointerType::get(IntegerType::get(M->getContext(), 8),100);//100 tytes
Type* struct_Ty[] = { struct_line->getType(),struct_filename->getType(),struct_dir->getType()};
llvm::StructType * struct_var= llvm::StructType::create(M->getContext(),"buginfor");
struct_var->setBody(struct_Ty);
Value* arg2 = struct_var;

Type* argsTy[] = { addr->getType(),arg2->getType()};
FunctionType *funcTy = FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(M->getContext()), ArrayRef<Type*>(argsTy, 2), false);
Function *hook;
hook = cast<Function>( M->getOrInsertFunction("__myfun", funcTy, attribute(M)));
CallInst *newInst = CallInst::Create(hook, ArrayRef<Value *>(args, 1), "");
```

anyone can tell me the right way to create a struct parameter like buginfor?

ps:
I want to get the three parameter and make it a llvm IR constantstruct

```
          DILocation Loc(N);    // DILocation is in DebugInfo.h
          unsigned Line = Loc.getLineNumber();
          StringRef File = Loc.getFilename();
          StringRef Dir = Loc.getDirectory();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'll want to create a ConstantStruct or an undef struct and then insert values in to it with insertvalue instructions. Depending on if you have constants or runtime values.

Comment: Yes, I just wang to get the debug information of an instruction and then make it a struct for my function as a parameter.

Comment: I want to get parameters from DILocation and make a new constantstruct.